# device locale is set to en_us after clearing app data

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a localized string resource A. I noticed that after I clear app data/cache (under setting), and open my activity (which belongs to that app), I always see resource A in en locale regardless of the current device language. If I go to setting again, change device language manually to whatever, and go back to my activity, then resource A is localized properly again.

I wondering why locale is set to default after app data/cache is cleared and is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I think, you need to setup the locale on the start of application.

Comment: How can I do that? I thought app locale is always sync-ed with language set in device setting but it doesn't work like that?

Comment: Can you please tell me what languages are you supporting?

Comment: My app supports en, fr, de, es, zh, ja.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky solution but you could set the locale in the launcher activity like this:

```
Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
config.locale = config.locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

You can also check the device locale to be absolutely sure that the device locale has changed.